# Jquery ui rotatable on zoom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI rotatable to rotate my div, its working fine when my div is set to 100% zoom. When I set the zoom less then 100% or greater then 100% then its not working properly.

I want it to be perfectly rotate on zoom in or zoom out my div.

I know here we need to write few lines of code to fix zoom issue.

**Here what I tried**

```
$('#target').rotatable({
  angle: false,        
  wheelRotate: true,   
  rotate: function(event, ui) {
  },  
  start: function(event, ui) {
  },  
  stop: function(event, ui) {
  },  
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `.rotatable()` is not a jQuery UI widget. You do not show how you "*set the zoom less than 100%*..." Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: here you can see jsFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/AbdullahSayyaf/a15vdtg0/10/
actually, I am trying to zoom the target element of a parent. so If i don't add CSS zoom property on container then the target element is perfectly rotating. but if I add the zoom property in my container, then the rotating behavior is changed using mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q2Lgh0st/12/

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="target">Rotate me!</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-rotatable-handle {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: 100%;
  bottom: inherit;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -21px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.container {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

#target {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".slide").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 2,
    step: 0.1,
    value: 0.5,
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("Slide", ui.value);
      $(".container").css("transform", "scale(" + ui.value + ")");
    }
  });
  $('#target').rotatable({
    // Callback fired on rotation start.
    start: function(event, ui) {},
    // Callback fired during rotation.
    rotate: function(event, ui) {},
    // Callback fired on rotation end.
    stop: function(event, ui) {},
    // Set the rotation center
  });
});
```

In regards to the `zoom`, please see:

> The non-standard `zoom` CSS property can be used to control the magnification level of an element. `transform: scale()` should be used instead of this property, if possible. However, unlike CSS Transforms, `zoom` affects the layout size of the element.

See More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

The last bit is what was most likely throwing off your Rotatable. Switching to the `transform`, there is no such issue found.